# How to use OWIN in asp.net 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I created my website with the asp.net preview template, I want to try to integrate azure AAD authentication into it.

https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/blob/master/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs

I already added the owin packages:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb -Prerelease
Installing NuGet package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.3.0.1.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.3.0.1' to WebApplication2.
PM> Install-Package Owin.Extensions
Installing NuGet package Owin.Extensions.0.8.5.
Successfully installed 'Owin.Extensions.0.8.5' to WebApplication2.
```

However Visual Studio does not detect yet the Usings

```
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
```

When I check the references is not there, I know it has changed quite a bit, but how can I make this reference work?

The project.json has the dependencies there:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-WebApplication2-93831a1b-8997-4395-9587-461f520d1546",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta4",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin": "2.2.1",
    "Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb": "3.0.1",
    "Owin.Extensions": "0.8.5"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000",
    "gen": "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { } //,
    //"dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "postrestore": [ "npm install", "bower install" ],
    "prepare": [ "gulp copy" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Your sample is not totally useful at vnext.

I think you should not use OWIN DLL with asp.net 5. I have read that OWIN was not totally ported to new framework yet.

Please, see this [sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/samples/OpenIdConnectSample/Startup.cs) for OpenId at vnext, maybe helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to run a restore before you can do anything with this. `dnu restore` should work.... if you're in visual studio, right click on the solution, get to the nuget manager and restore packages